# How to debounce a controlled input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I'm currently struggling with react inputs and debounce from lodash.
Most of the time when I have a form I also have an edit option, so I need a controlled component to fill back the inputs using `value={state["targetValue"]}` so I can fill and edit the field.

However, if the component is controlled debounce isn't working.
I made a simple example on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/icy-cloud-ydzj2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { debounce } from "lodash";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      title: "",
      editMode: false
    };
    this.debouncedEvent = React.createRef();
  }

  debounceEvent(_fn, timer = 500, options = null) {
    this.debouncedEvent.current = debounce(_fn, timer, options);
    return e => {
      e.persist();
      return this.debouncedEvent.current(e);
    };
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.debouncedEvent.current.cancel();
  }

  onChangeValue = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    this.setState(() => {
      return { [name]: value };
    });
  };

  onRequestEdit = () => {
    this.setState({ name: "Abla blabla bla", editMode: true });
  };

  onCancelEdit = () => {
    if (this.state.editMode) this.setState({ name: "", editMode: false });
  };

  onSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Submiting", this.state.name);
  };

  render() {
    const { name, editMode } = this.state;
    const isSubmitOrEditLabel = editMode ? `Edit` : "Submit";
    console.log("rendering", name);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1> How to debounce controlled input ?</h1>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.onRequestEdit}>
          Fill with dummy data
        </button>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.onCancelEdit}>
          Cancel Edit Mode
        </button>
        <div style={{ marginTop: "25px" }}>
          <label>
            Controlled / Can be used for editing but not with debounce
          </label>
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <input
              required
              type="text"
              name="name"
              value={name}
              placeholder="type something"
              // onChange={this.onChangeValue}
              onChange={this.debounceEvent(this.onChangeValue)}
            />
            <button type="submit">{isSubmitOrEditLabel}</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div style={{ marginTop: "25px" }}>
          <label> Uncontrolled / Can't be used for editing </label>
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <input
              required
              type="text"
              name="name"
              placeholder="type something"
              onChange={this.debounceEvent(this.onChangeValue)}
            />
            <button type="submit">{isSubmitOrEditLabel}</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: What are you trying to debounce exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to debounce my input field so they do not trigger a re-render on setState until the user has completed typing. In the sample I posted, the second input works as intended but it can't be use on an edit mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So... Apparently, there's no solution. the input takes the value from the state. While debounce prevents the state to trigger.

I made a workaround using ReactDOM.

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export const setFormDefaultValue = (obj, ref) => {
  if (ref && !ref.current) return;

  if (!obj || !obj instanceof Object) return;

  const _this = [
    ...ReactDOM.findDOMNode(ref.current).getElementsByClassName("form-control")
  ];

  if (_this.length > 0) {
    _this.forEach(el => {
      if (el.name in obj) el.value = obj[el.name];
      else console.error(`Object value for ${el.name} is missing...`);
    });
  }
};
```

and then the use:

```
this.refForm = React.createRef();
setFormDefaultValue(this.state, refForm)
```

This way I can fill my form with the state default value and continue using debounce.

Answer (score 6):

At first it looks impossible, but there is a simple way to do it.
Just create the debounce function expression outside the react component.

Here is a pseudo example, for modern React with Hooks:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { debounce } from "lodash";
...


const getSearchResults = debounce((value, dispatch) => {
  dispatch(getDataFromAPI(value));
}, 800);



const SearchData = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    getSearchResults(inputValue, dispatch);
  }, [inputValue]);

 ...

 return (
   <>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search..."
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={e => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
      />
      ...
   </>
 );
};

export default SearchData;
```

**Update:** In time I came up with a better solution using "useCallback"

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { debounce } from "lodash";
...


const SearchData = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  ...

  const getSearchResults = useCallback(
    debounce(value => {
      dispatch(getDataFromAPI(value));
    }, 800),
    []
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    getSearchResults(inputValue);
  }, [inputValue]);

 ...

 return (
   <>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search..."
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={e => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
      />
      ...
   </>
 );
};
```

Comment: I would love to understand why the function has to be outside the component? It works great but only if it's outside. Blows my mind. Thank you though

Comment: Hey Andy,
useState triggers component rerender every time its value is changed.
So every single time the component renders getSearchResults is being recreated over and over again and it can't perform its tasks as we expect.
That is why I just declare the function outside the compound scope to prevent recreating.

At the time I wrote this solution it was pretty good for me, but nowadays I have more in-depth knowledge in React, so I will add even better and more convenient solution in the post

You can reed more for useState, Controlled components in React docs:
https://reactjs.org/docs

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, useMemo and debounce from lodash seem to work for me.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import { debounce } from 'lodash';

const Search = () => {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setInputValue(event.target.value);
    };

    const handleFetch = (input) => {
        // do stg
    };

    const debouncedFetch = useMemo(() => debounce(handleFetch, 500), []);

    useEffect(() => {
        debouncedFetch(inputValue);
    }, [inputValue]);

    return (   
        <Form>
            <input
                type="text"
                value={inputValue}
                onChange={handleChange}
             />
             // rest of the component
        </Form>
    );
};
```

Some articles that helped me:
https://dev.to/alexdrocks/using-lodash-debounce-with-react-hooks-for-an-async-data-fetching-input-2p4g
https://www.carlrippon.com/using-lodash-debounce-with-react-and-ts/
https://blog.logrocket.com/how-and-when-to-debounce-or-throttle-in-react/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';

function usePrevious(value: any) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
}

const DeboucnedInput = React.memo(({ value, onChange }) => {
  const [localValue, setLocalValue] = useState('');
  const prevValue = usePrevious(value);
  const ref = useRef();
  ref.current = _.debounce(onChange, 500);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!_.isNil(value) && prevValue !== value && localValue !== value) {
      setLocalValue(value);
    }
  }, [value]);

  const debounceChange = useCallback(
    _.debounce(nextValue => {
      onChange(nextValue);
    }, 1000),
    []
  );

  const handleSearch = useCallback(
    nextValue => {
      if (nextValue !== localValue) {
        setLocalValue(nextValue);
        debounceChange(nextValue);
      }
    },
    [localValue, debounceChange]
  );


  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={localValue}
      onChange={handleSearch}
    />
  );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this lib: https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-debounce

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useDebounce } from 'use-debounce';

export default function Input() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('Hello');
  const [value] = useDebounce(text, 1000);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        defaultValue={'Hello'}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setText(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <p>Actual value: {text}</p>
      <p>Debounce value: {value}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, unfortunately, I can't use hooks at the moment. Also, this will still trigger a re-rendering each time we write in the input since we're editing ```text``` instead of ```value```.

Comment: It's not a solution to your problem...it is an example of the behavior of debounce...It's made to compare both flows..